# I have data on the front end but it's undefined in the back end

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hello guys i have a problem with my data on the fetch indeed on the front side i do this to fetch my data:

```
() => {
              const data = {clubChoix: element.nomClub};

              const options = {
                method: 'POST',
                body: data,
              };

              fetch('http://localhost:8080/inscription/choixclub', options)
                .then((response) => {
                  return response.json();
                })
                .then(
                  (responseData) => {
                    console.log(responseData);
                  },
                  (err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                  },
                );
            })
```

And the i put a console.log to make sure that what i send is real

```
(console.log(element.nomClub),
```

The result of this one is:

```
LOG: Nimes Olympique
```

In my thought the "const data = {choixClub: element.nomClub};" in the data is like a req.body.clubChoix but in the back end so why when i console log it the req.body it's undefined ?

in case you want to see my back end there it is:

```
  choixClub: (req, res) => {
    User.updateOne(
      { _id: "5f47a46e36588f5e2a1e4f35" },
      {
        $set: {
          club: req.body.clubChoix,
        },
      },

      (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.json({ message: "une erreur s'est produite" });
        } else {
          console.log(req.body.clubChoix);
          res.json({ message: "Votre club a bien été enregistré" });
        }
      }
    );
  },
```

Comment: you have clubChoix on back and choixClub for the front ... not the same key

Comment: My bad i forgot to edit but they are the same

Comment: can you share more from your backend, like midlleware used

Comment: @AurelioLIMAFERREIRA     const cors = {
  handle: (req, res, next) => {
    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
      process.env.ORIGIN || "http://localhost:3000"
    );
    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
    );
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, POST, DELETE, GET");
      return res.status(200).json({});
    }
    next();
  },
};

module.exports = cors;

Comment: did you have something like bodyparser ?

Comment: No i don't have

Comment: install bodyparser and add bodyparser line (midlleware) 

const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

Comment: The console log in the back end is still undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220561/discussion-between-aurelio-lima-ferreira-and-arnaud-p).